# C# XAML Binding of a default with IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a reason why my code isn't doing its job:
In XAML I use:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Txt_8, Converter={StaticResource DefKonverter}, ConverterParameter='UserAlias'}"/>
```

In C# there are an IValueConverter which giving me a default value when the ConverterParameter='UserAlias'. For ex. the string 'Jettero'. This works well for that point I see in my TextBox the text 'Jettero'.
I saving my record to database, but in the record Txt_8 still NULL ! (Other fields are saved well)
Looks like the Binding not updating the record field behind the TextBox.

=========== Update start

**CONCLUSION: This is not working because the Binding working in one direction. The Converter good for showing special things what makes your user experince better but not to save it.**

=========== Update end

A similar issue backward happens also, In XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Date_1, Converter={StaticResource DefKonverter}, ConverterParameter='\{0:yyyy-MM-dd\}TimeStamp'}"/>
```

This working as it should in the record behind: when I write in the TextBox the '.' character it 'translates' to the today's date. After I save the record, it contains the date.
But in the TextBox I still see the written '.'.
In this sit the Binding not updating the TextBox over the record.

=========== Update start

**CONCLUSION: This is not working well because the Binding working in one direction. The Converter good for change the data in that shape how you wanna store.**

**What is still not answered: when I convert '.' into the present date, it is not showing that - now I see the reason. BUT in the Converter if I'm using a Modal window to somehow extend the data what I wrote in (finding a full text for a keyword), that extended information SHOWS UP in my TextBox beside to store of it.**

=========== Update end

I don't know what I miss... I checked lot of using of the default and IValueConverter solutions, but this simple sit never came up. Can anyone help?

Comment: During Debug, open Output window (View -> Output, Ctrl + Alt + O) and search for Binding Errors. If there any, please insert them here. That will give us more information.

Comment: Very good idea! I've one binding type:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsExpanded' property not found on 'object' ''RTFBox' (Name='FeladatRTFdoboz')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsExpanded; DataItem='RTFBox' (Name='FeladatRTFdoboz'); target element is 'GridSplitter' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
but this not connected with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be expecting behaviour from a value converter for which it wasn't designed. What is happening is:

On rendering the textbox, the binding reads a value, let's say `null`, from your property Txt_8, passes that to the converter, which gives it the value to render, in your example 'Jettero'. This means that the visual representation of your `null` is `Jettero`. This isn't meant to (and won't) consequently replace your null with 'Jettero' because, according to the binding engine, it has successfully loaded the value from the source and returned it to the target.

The `ConvertBack` method of the value converter is supposed to cater for the scenario where the value is changed on the UI and needs to be converted back for storage.

Moral of the story: don't use a value converter for specifying a "default" value for the binding. If your property needs a default value, assign it that in your constructor or initializer. If you want your property value to change itself as it is assigned a value, implement it there, instead of in the converter.

For instance, you can define a Date property like this instead of using a converter:

```
// disclaimer: untested pseudo-code
private DateTime? _dateTimeField;

public string SomeDateProperty
{
   get { return _dateTimeField.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'); }
   set 
   { 
      if (value == '.') 
        value = DateTime.Today.ToString();

      _dateTimeField = DateTime.Parse(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't use a C# function because the XAML loaded by my program and used as ListView DataTemplate.

Comment: I've seen was you mean. I tried in the Binding the "TargetNullValue='Jettero'" as test with similar result: showing nicely but not saving. I think it should give a binded value but not.
I can't use a C# function calling because the XAML loaded by my program and used as ListView DataTemplate. I can use through StaticResouce and in Binding functions.
How can I implement this code into my XAML?

Comment: There is an interesting thing in the same IValueConverter what is the contrary to the ConvertBack part of your Answer:
When I write in a String connected TextBox part of my Partner name, it gives back the full name - and this works well!
Could it be difference in String and DateTime handling?

Comment: Hi, I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: On what class is the "Txt_8" property then? Perhaps include your DataTemplate, classes and parts of your XAML in your question so I can better understand.

Comment: It is just a field of a Table what is in a DataSet. It comes from an SQL database

Comment: The DataTemplate switched by a DataTemplateSelector class.\n
DataTemplate is complex but easy as:\n
<DataTemplate x:Key="FejlesztesiIgeny_1">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource FL_timestamp}" Text="{Binding Path=Datum_1,Converter={StaticResource AlapKonverter}, ConverterParameter='\{0:yyyy-MM-dd\}TimeStamp'}"/>
</DataTemplate>
I can send you the IValueConverter what doing all the job of the different type of special conversions. The point there is just a return (DateTime)x; or return (String)x;

Comment: Found an other difference:
 CegKivalaszt dialog = new CegKivalaszt(value.ToString());
 dialog.ShowDialog();
 return dialog.Result;\n
So there should happen a LostFocus and GotFocus event.

Comment: Hi Jettero, sorry I've been away for a while. This is why using a dataset as a datasource is a bad idea. I'd suggest making a set of classes (ViewModels) to carry the  data to allow you to modify the property and add the behaviour you want.

Comment: You wrote, the problem because the Binding, not the layer under, though I'm not sure how can I implement the DataSet functionality in a ViewModel.

Comment: For the default data I can not use any system under my XAML because then I lose the point why I'm using loaded DataTemplate: In the database I have one table, and one field of that table can be used for different data on different row. The XAML defines for what. Is the ViewModel good for this type of situation?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But it basically comes down to binding to a custom class, rather than a field in a dataset. It is the easiest to program against WPF if you follow the MVVM approach. Think about it like this: you should be able to get the same behaviour if you interact with the class than you would get if you interacted with the UI. I'll need to post somewhere else to go into more depth however.

Comment: Yes, the post or link for an example would be good. I read about MVVM several places, but don't U really/exactly what It is all about. I think I don't know enough in english, to see the point (last day I tried to read several, but did not U what is the difference). An example would help - if you have an easy one. If you couldn't send, no problem, I write it in my list, to search for later.